# Editing existing entity and saving doesn't save

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm having an issue trying to save an existing entity object - it just doesn't save it.

Here's what I have in my repository

```
private MyEntities _entities;

public EFUserFoldersRepository(MyEntities entities)
{
    _entities = entities;
}

public void SaveUserFolder(UserFolder userFolder)
{
    if (userFolder.UserFolderID == 0)         // new user folder
        _entities.UserFolders.Add(userFolder);
    else
        _entities.UserFolders.Attach(userFolder);

    _entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

If I'm creating a folder, this works fine, the object gets created. But if I'm editing an existing folder and use the `Attach` method, nothing happens.

Is there something additional I need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the context entry .State property to EntityState.Modified as in the following example:

Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context

If you have an entity that you know already exists in the database but to which changes may have been made then you can tell the context to attach the entity and set its state to Modified. For example:

```
var existingBlog = new Blog { BlogId = 1, Name = "ADO.NET Blog" };

using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Modified;

    // Do some more work... 

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Example taken from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Your SaveUserFolder would then look like this:

```
public void SaveUserFolder(UserFolder userFolder)
{
    if (userFolder.UserFolderID == 0)         // new user folder
        _entities.UserFolders.Add(userFolder);
    else
    {
        _entities.UserFolders.Attach(userFolder);
        _entities.Entry(userFolder).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    _entities.SaveChanges();
}
```